# How to compare objects in STL data structure

Tags: java, class, data-structures, compare, utility

(this question pertains to java)
I tried looking around for this.. gotten some partial answers but nothing that really could help me.
If I have a class pair with 2 variables inside of it, and insert it into a HashSet or TreeSet, how would I access those elements after I insert it. 
Ex:

```
HashSet<Integer>hs=new HashSet<>();
hs.add(new pair(1,2));
hs.get(new pair(1,2));
```

So here it would throw a null pointer exception, because it is getting a seperate address. How do I modify the data structure to have some sort of comparator that we can compare the actualy elements inside such as : a==other.a && b==other.b

Comment: What do you mean with STL? Also _"getting a separate address"_ seems to indicate you're thinking to much in terms of pointers, and that is not how Java works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is to override equals and hashCode methods for your pair class. For example:

```
class Pair {
    int a;
    int b;

    Pair(int a, int b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(other: Object) {
        if (other == null) { return false; }
        if (other instanceof Pair) {
            Pair otherPair = (Pair)other;
            return a == otherPair.a && b == otherPair.b;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return a * 31 + b;
    }
}
```

To learn more, read about equals and hashCode methods in java.lang.Object, and read HashSet documentation.

Comment: Cool thanks... Also wanted to ask though, in a TreeSet<pair>.... it would not utilize the hashcode() function at all right? One reason I'm hesitant to use a hashcode bymyself,though, is because HashSet takes care of collisions automatically for you... do you know if it still does the same if you overide the hashcode?

Comment: @BobKalobsky `HashSet` uses the hashcode of the objects it contains, if you don't override it, things will not work, because each different object will have its own hashcode, instead of one derived from its content. I would also recommend that you read the Java apidoc, because your question regarding `TreeSet` is answered in [its apidoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html)